# Partitioning an open set into a convex and non-convex set

Tags: general-topology, convex-geometry

Suppose I had an open set $X\in \mathbb{R}^n$, and I wish to partition it into two sets $U$ and $V$ where $U$ is the *largest* possible convex set contained in $X$ and $V$ is some "residual" open set, and $X=U\bigcup V$.

How would I find $U,V$? Also would the answer change is $U$ is closed convex vs open convex, or if the closure $cl(U)\subset X$ vs. $cl(U)$ NOT contained in $X$.

**Edit** for my purposes, I am mostly interested in bounded sets, but I would also like to study the unbounded case.

Comment: What would you expect for an answer if $X$ were shaped like a dumbbell? Edit the question to show us some pictures of that and other examples.

Comment: Other cases of interest are an open annulus in $\Bbb R^2$, $(0,1) \cup (2,3)$ in$ \Bbb R^1$, $\bigcup (2n^2,(2n+1)^2)$ in $\Bbb R^1$

Comment: What about disconnected sets?